# Issue response in json

Tags: java, json, struts2

I am working in struts2 with json ,my job is to convert net code to java i am struggling in converting the following code, is that any object to call json without using response and request

```
//clears the existing HTML
    Response.Clear();
//change content type       
    Response.ContentType = CommonConstants.Common.CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_PLAIN;  
    Response.Write(strJSON.ToString());
//writes out the new name       
    Response.End();
```

the above code is .net i am struggling to convert to java . becuase i should not use HttpServletRequest or HttpServletResponse object .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Without using httpservletresponse, how can u send your json to the response. I dont think its possible

Comment: I am not 100% sure so, i am asking you people may aware of something Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You need the response, even though that might be hidden from you. [See here](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8/docs/json-plugin.html)

You can get the response in your action by implementing `ServletResponseAware`

Comment: are u mean like this servletResponse() , how we can set value here